# boost::asio bind exception when binding a endpoint

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I make a server using boost::asio. And I have a problem with binding to a endpoint.
So, if I init an acceptor in a constructor:

```
Server::Server(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 5555))
```

and after use it:

```
void Dialog::start_accept()
{
sockets.push_back(socket_ptr(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service)));
acceptor.async_accept(*(sockets[sockets.size() - 1]), boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, sockets[sockets.size() - 1], _1));
}
```

it works fine. Server::handle_accept calls when a new client is connecting.
But I want to connect to an arbitrary endpoint. And I add binding to this endpoint. Acceptor is a class member. sockets is an array of shared_ptr to asio sockets.
If I add just:

```
void Server::start_accept()
{
sockets.push_back(socket_ptr(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service)));
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);
acceptor.bind(endpoint);
acceptor.async_accept(*(sockets[sockets.size() - 1]), boost::bind(&Dialog::handle_accept, this, sockets[sockets.size() - 1], _1));
}
```

I get exception Wrong argument. I try:

```
void Server::start_accept()
{
sockets.push_back(socket_ptr(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service)));
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);
acceptor.close();
acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
acceptor.bind(endpoint);
acceptor.async_accept(*(sockets[sockets.size() - 1]), boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, sockets[sockets.size() - 1], _1));
}
```

but I get the same.
So, how can I reuse the acceptor to rebind to a new address?
OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can see it here https://github.com/denprog/CameraServer.

Comment: It is a working one. But I want to bind a new endpoint in in start_accept().

Comment: Define 'arbitrary endpoint'.

Comment: It's an endpoint with an address and port which I define in start_accept: boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);. In other words, I change the port here and I want to listen connections from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the question. I delete the acceptor and create a new one. Now acceptor is boost::scoped_ptr acceptor.

```
try
{
    if (acceptor && acceptor->is_open())
    {
        acceptor->cancel();
        acceptor->close();
    }
    acceptor.reset(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), arg1.toInt())));
    acceptor->set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
}
catch (const boost::system::system_error& error)
{
    add_log("Error accepting");
}
```